# What is the Prayaschitha for plucking Peepal leaves?

Tags: scripture, curse, skanda-purana, prayaschitta, peepal-tree

[Why should not we touch Tulsi and Peepal trees on Sunday?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9585/why-should-not-we-touch-tulsi-and-peepal-trees-on-sunday/56154#56154)

As far as the Peepal Tree (aśvattha) is considered, not only on Sundays, but it shouldn't be touched on any other day except on Saturdays.

This prescription follows from the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa 2.4.3.48

Chapter 3, Kārttikamāsa-māhātmya, Vaiṣṇava-khaṇḍa, Skanda-purāṇa

अश्वत्थपूजा स्पर्शेन कर्त्तव्या शनिवासरे ।
अन्यवारेऽश्वत्थसंगाद्दरिद्रो जायते नरः ॥ ४८ ॥

The worship of Aśvattha should be conducted on Saturdays by touching it. On other days if a man touches it he will become poor.

Comment: First of all no leaves or flowers are suppose to be pluck. Even for worship.we are suppose to use the ones fallen on ground.

Comment: @Carmensandiego. Wrong. Articles which are to be used in holy rites are expressly forbidden to be kept on ground, as the ground is considered naturally impure.

Comment: @Carmensandiego exactly the opposite is true .. flowers fallen on ground are not to be used in Puja .. flowers and leaves are to be plucked using fingers after bath .. there are specific methods and restrictions of how to pluck them and different mantras for plucking different leaves etc.

Comment: I think the above verse applies only for Kartika Masam. Read 48th point. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371644.html

Comment: @অনু - noted. Will look it up

Comment: @Rickross - will check it out. Maybe I am conflating it with fruits. Is it the case that fruits are not suppose to be plucked from trees ?

Comment: Manusmriti 1.47 says that hermit should only eat leaves and fruits that have fallen. So it cannot be the case that ground is considered impure. Trying to find injunction which says plucked leaves and flowers are to be used for puja @অনু